# Java: 1.1: Creating instance of class from that class. 1.2: Threading the instantiation

Tags: java, multithreading, class, download, instantiation

I have been downloading a .java-file from the internet that contains some code that I'm not quite familiar with. The name of the file is "Class1.java".

**Class1.java**

```
public class Class1 implements Runnable {
       public static Class1 instantiation1 = null;

       public static void main(String[] args) {
              instantiation1 = new Class1();

              (new Thread(instantiation1)).start();
       }

       public void run() {
              /* Do whatever the threads should do.
                 I don't think this part is so important... */
       }
}
```

**1.1: Creating instance of class from that class.**

```
public static Class1 instantiation1 = null;
instantiation1 = new Class1();
```

Why is Class1 making an instance of itself? Does this behavior have it's own name?

**1.2: Threading the instantiation.**

```
(new Thread(instantiation1)).start();
```

Is it common to use an instantiation as a thread instead of creating a thread like this:

```
Thread <thread name> = new Thread();
```

I'm looking forward for questions and answers.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

1.1. This is the right thing to do, if you want to run instance (non-static) methods on Class1; in your case, you need this as you need to pass the Class1 instance to the Thread constructor on the next line.

1.2. This is normal, you have 2 ways to create a Thread (by extending Thread or by implementing Runnable), here this code uses the Runnable approach (i.e. this is the second approach); the 1st approach is the one you mentioned (but then Class1 would need to extend Thread).

Answer (score 1):

1.1: You may be confused because of the name "Class1". It's the name of the class, as is "Socket", "XMLReader", or whatever. It's in no way related to it being a "Class" object, it's a perfectly normal. If you read the start as Socket _socket = new Socket(); it makes sense, right ? Try renaming (alt-shift-R if you use eclipse) "Class1" to "MyRunnableObject" and it will be better :)

1.2: The thread as as nothing to do with the "instantation" of the class, despite of his name. The object has been created before, and now, it is run, as can be any runnable. Rename "instantation" to "_runnable" , and suddenly, it makes more sense :)

I feel you were mislead by poor variable naming, if that's not the case, pardon my inappropriate answer :)

Comment: Thank you both! The explanation that you can't use the class' non-static variables or methods without operating an instance of the very class itself helped clean up a lot for me.

C4stor; I had difficulties understanding why an initiation were taking place in the very same class as the initiation pointed to, and I still have difficulties understanding why the code is using the initiation of the class as a thread, either if it's using the initiation itself or if it's just calling the thread "Class1" regardless of how the initiation is.

Sorry if my comment turned out a bit messy...